# Can I compare a char* (month) with a string (February)? If not, how can I go about doing this?

Tags: c++, character

I want the program to work so that I can turn any worded month to its equivalent number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
   char month[20];
   int INT_month;

   cout << "Enter a month: (ex. January, February)";
   cin >> month;  // Let's say the input is February

   if (month == "February")
       INT_month = 2; 

   cout << "The month in its' integral form is " << INT_month << endl;
                                  // INT_month = 2130567168 // WHY DOES IT DO THIS????

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mind elaborating on what your problem is?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake in the question. I meant to say 'array' instead of 'string'.
Why isn't the 'INT_month' variable not being '2'?

Comment: I meant that your desription should elaborate more on the title.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is creating a `vector` of month names, and using the look-up index plus one as the month number:

```
vector<string> months = {
    "january", "february", "march", ...
};
string search = "march";
auto pos = find(months.begin(), months.end(), search);
if (pos != months.end()) {
    cout << "Month number: " << distance(months.begin(), pos) + 1 << endl;
} else {
    cerr << "Not found" << endl;
}
```

This prints 3 ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/BVW8Xb)).